# AngularJS Event for view focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am searching for and AngularJS event to do some animation when I go to a specific view.

For now I use ng-init but I saw that if I go to my view with the browser BACK button init is not called (because the view partial is loading once).

So if you know how to call my own function when we go to a specific view I will be happy, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {})`?

(Alternatively, you can set it up on `$rootScope` if your doing so in a `run()` or a service call)